# Data table will not work in shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, shinydashboard, dt

If shinydashboard was a person I would like to meet him in a dark alley with a baseball bat. I am simply trying show a data frame as a table in my shiny app so I looked online at a bunch websites and questions on stack exchange and this is what I got.

**UI**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(data.table)#For fread.
library(tidyverse)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(DT)#For the interactive table.


# Header -----------------------------------------------------------------------|
header<-dashboardHeader( title = "Marketing Dashboard"
  
)


# Sidebar ----------------------------------------------------------------------|

sidebar<-dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Overview", tabname ="overview", icon = icon("dashboard")),
    menuItem("Weather", tabname ="weather", icon = icon("bolt"))
  )
)

# Body -------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  
body<-dashboardBody( 
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = 'overview',
        DT::dataTableOutput("overviewtable")
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = 'weather',
      fluidRow(
        
      )
    )
  )
)



# UI ---------------------------------------------------------------------------|

ui = dashboardPage(
  header,
  sidebar,
  body
)

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

**Server**

```
server <- function(input,output){
  
  #Table for overview
  output$overviewtable<- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(tib1)
  })
  
}
```

I have tried using `tableOutput` and `renderTable`
I have tried to see if my **tib1** was somehow the problem so I tried using the data set **mpg**. That didnt work. I tried placing  `DT::dataTableOutput("overviewtable")` in a column(), in a fluidRow. I tried reinstalling the packages for **DT** and refreshing R but that didnt work. I looked at the gallery website from R [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/basic-datatable.html). I took that code and ran it and I was able to see their table they made but when I ran my code I cant see my table at all or other tables for that matter. I have a feeling it has something to do with shinydashboard because it seems that when I ran the code from the website above that was just using shiny it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a typo in the `tabName =`  argument:

```
sidebar<-dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Overview", tabName ="overview", icon = icon("dashboard")),
    menuItem("Weather", tabName ="weather", icon = icon("bolt"))
  )
)
```

Comment: When i would run the code I would get no error message and I would even see both of the tabs but that was indeed the problem. Thanks!